# Unknown Japanese saying: 世に孵ることを拒む卵はなく、　芽吹くことを拒む種子もあり得ない

Tags: translation, word-choice, usage, phrase-requests

I'm having some issues translating the first part (bolded) of this metaphor/saying(?) into English.

> **世に孵ることを拒む卵はなく**、　芽吹くことを拒む種子もあり得ない.

How does the verb 孵る work on the こと part of the sentence, and does the full sentence end in the adjectival phrase "あり得ない" or does it end with a nai-form "得"?

The two possible translations I have at the moment are:

> In life to hatch out is a circumstance that to prevent the infant’s
>   cries, is impossible as the seed denys its circumstances to bud.

and

> In society to hatch out is an occurrence that to prevent the infant’s
>   cries, is as impossible as the seed rejecting its circumstances to
>   bud.

Comment: Where are you seeing the part about the infant's cries?

Comment: @mamster the "infant" I got from the kanji 卵, which can mean "infancy", "origin", "beginning", "egg", and "expert (in the making)". The "cries" I got from the "なく" in the bolded part, although according to the Japanese-English dictionary, なく can also be translated as "to howl, to cry, to weep, to sob, to sing (bird)," etc. I honestly doubt my own translation for that part though, so any help or corrections would be much appreciated.

Comment: For some reason, you are "seeing" so many things that are just not said in the original sentence.  The structure of that sentence is actually VERY simple.

Comment: @l'électeur Then may you please help me "see" the simplicity of the sentence structure, as you are correct in that I am seeing too many things when it comes to this sentence.

Comment: All the usages of `naku` you listed above are almost always written in Kanji.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me break it down to smaller chunks...

世に孵ることを拒む refuse to hatch into this world (← relative clause that modifies 卵)
卵 egg
は (topic particle)
なく don't exist (← continuative form of ない(無い))
芽吹くことを拒む refuse to germinate (← relative clause that modifies 種子)
種子 seed
も either
あり得ない can not exist

To put them back together, I think it means something like...

> 世に孵ることを拒む卵はなく、芽吹くことを拒む種子もあり得ない。

"There are no eggs that refuse to hatch into this world, and there cannot be seeds that refuse to sprout out, either."

Comment: Quick question: how do you know that 世に孵ることを拒む is a relative clause? ( Is it because it is before the egg, which in turn is before the topic particle?) (Its been ages since I've taken a class that delt with "relative clauses" and "sub-something-that-I-can't-remember clauses"... I need to go and do a refresh in basic grammer, haha.

Comment: It's simply because it's a short-form verb that directly precedes a noun.